# Stream to FFServer without FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, ffserver

I have just started exploring and developing streaming applications to stream media to **FFServer**...

The basic format would be to use **FFmpeg** either using `command line` or `JNI` to stream media to **FFServer**...

But is it possible to stream media to `ffserver` using the available `native api`'s available on the **Android** / **WP8** / **iOS** platform or any other platorm rather than using the traditional way through `ffmpeg`...?

Thanks...